# Can you get Painted or Certified items in Rocket League with trade-ins?

Tags: rocket-league

The June update recently added a rare chance for Painted items (wheels/toppers with different colours) or Certified items that track a different stat than usual to drop after matches. I wasn't able to find any information on whether or not trading in my existing toppers (e.g. 5 uncommon --> 1 rare) can result in a Painted or Certified topper. Can anyone advise as to whether they have obtained a Painted/Certified item through a trade-in as opposed to a random drop?

Comment: I've only ever got decals for DLC cars as my first-level (Rare) trade-ins and never painted or certified items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most certainly possible to get a painted and/or certified from a trade up. Below are two video examples of getting a painted, and then a painted and certified item from a trade up. These items are from the latest Turbo crate but the rules apply to any items traded up.

### Trade ups

---

[Painted Endo](https://youtu.be/W2yr0_IPLRs?t=11m7s)

[Painted and Certified Tachyon](https://youtu.be/WDCtL89DSfg?t=10m39s)

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten a painted Drink Helmet (it was yellow but had a fancy name to it) and I ended up trading a drink helmet, and 4 dominus royalty's for a Hearts trail, so I cannot provide a screenshot. But trust me, Psyonix also said that not all toppers are painted, but you know...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sky blue trade-up Zeta wheels]
Yes, it is possible. I managed to trade up some old uncommon toppers and got a painted zeta, no doubt you can get certified too.

Comment: It should be better to have a verified information, such as a dev validation, or a wiki entry, etc. "no doubt" is not enough.

Comment: @V4karian A screenshot is pretty darn verified.  Dev validation is not necessary, and a wiki entry, being publically editable, is just as good as what we have.